# adopt popup from blend and to visual studio windows phone 8

Tags: user-interface, popup, windows-phone-8, blend

We are trying to implement a popup window.

This we are doing by making a popup in Blend, which we interpret as a style ? Because of its variable name in visual studio. We have tried to give

myPopup.style = blendPopupStyle;

But when displaying it the style is lost.
Can somebody explain a mock up of how to do this?

Furthermore the popup should scale out the background so as not to make people able to click anything else than the UI on the popup.

An example is here http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/06/12/Modal-Dialogs-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx but it is only working for windows 8. And when trying to port I have not been able to find a way. But this still leaves the blend issue.

Hope somebody have an example / tutorial, or some pointers :)

**Answer**

The error is in where you in blend position your popup model. it should be where the other elements are as a popup element. Then you can simply by NAME.isopen = true;.

If you want a background that is not accesible in the meantime of popup and you do not want a hugh popup. simply open a popup with an appropriate opacity &/| colour. And then open your blend model done :)

Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stands in the question. Rewritten:

The error is in where you in blend position your popup model. it should be where the other elements are as a popup element. Then you can simply by NAME.isopen = true;.

If you want a background that is not accesible in the meantime of popup and you do not want a hugh popup. simply open a popup with an appropriate opacity &/| colour. And then open your blend model done :)